# Servicestack automap update endpoints

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

We are using ServiceStack QueryDb to expose certain business objects for auto-querying, and it is working great.

```
    [Route("/catalog/customers")]
    [Authenticate]
    public class QueryCustomers : QueryDb<ServiceModel.Catalog.Customer> { }
```

We'd like to implement some sort of UpdateDb that auto-maps authenticated POST, PUT and DELETE requests to insert, update and delete auto-mapped predefined OrmLite business objects, but don't see any examples on the web.  Ideally, we could create an endpoint as simple as:

```
    [Route("/edits/customers")]
    [Authenticate]
    public class UpdateCustomers : UpdateDb<ServiceModel.Catalog.Customer> { }
```

I'd prefer to not have to roll our own if this has already been done somewhere in the ServiceStack library or elsewhere...  Is this something that ServiceStack already supports, or are we on our own in developing this UpdateDb utility?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would require a **CRUD version** of [AutoQuery](https://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) which doesn't exist yet so you would need to implement your Update services as normal.

Comment: Thank you very much - with a decompiler and a little bit of headache it's looking like I should be able to put something together pretty quickly.  Thanks for everything your team does to make the ServiceStack utilities as powerful as they are!

Comment: np :) Also the [source code for AutoQuery's impl](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs) should help with creating a similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't done a lot of testing, but it looks like the UpdateDb will involve one tweak against the QueryDb implementation -

```
        public long CreateUpdate<From>(IUpdateDb<From> dto, Dictionary<string, string> dynamicParams, IRequest req = null)
        {
            long result;
            var db = GetDb<From>(req);

            var body = req.GetRawBody();

            var jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(body);
            var obj = jsonObject.ConvertTo<From>();

            var id = (obj as IHasId<int>)?.Id;

            if (id == null)
                throw new Exception("Cannot update without identity field defined");

            if (req.Verb == "DELETE")
            {
                result = db.DeleteById<From>(id);
            }
            else if (req.Verb == "POST")
            {
                db.InsertAll(new[] { obj });
                result = ((IHasId<int>)obj).Id;
            }
            else
            {
                result = db.UpdateOnly(obj,
                    jsonObject.Keys.ToArray(),
                    u => ((IHasId<int>)u).Id == id);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't be re-parsing the body like this as the Request DTO is already deserialized and this will only work with JSON Services. If you want to retrieve the Request DTO as a dictionary you can use [ToObjectDictionary()](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping#populating-types-from-an-object-dictionary) ext method, for any untyped (i.e. not on Request DTO) you can fetch them from the Request.QueryString/FormData collections.